# I don't understand this error, "Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" ? Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to take screenshot from specifics urls
It actually works with some Urls but not all of them.

Here is the error I have with this url

(https://candidat.pole-emploi.fr/offres/recherche/detail/136QBXM) :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

2022-07-05T02:07:36.878958+00:00 app[worker.1]:
File "/app/main.py", line 132, in <module>
2022-07-05T02:07:36.879133+00:00 app[worker.1]:     
driver.get("https://candidat.pole-emploi.fr/offres/recherche/detail/136QBXM")
2022-07-05T02:07:36.879146+00:00 app[worker.1]:
File"/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 447, in get
2022-07-05T02:07:36.879379+00:00 app[worker.1]:self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
2022-07-05T02:07:36.879389+00:00 app[worker.1]:
File"/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 435, in execute
2022-07-05T02:07:36.879613+00:00 
app[worker.1]:self.error_handler.check_response(response)
2022-07-05T02:07:36.879625+00:00 app[worker.1]:
File"/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/
sitepackages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in 
check_response
2022-07-05T02:07:36.879775+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise 
exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
2022-07-05T02:07:36.879808+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknownerror:net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Here is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from PIL import Image
import io
from PIL import ImageOps

op=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
op.add_argument("--headless")
op.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
op.add_argument("--disable-dev-sh-usage")
op.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver =webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"),options=op)

driver.get('https://candidat.pole-emploi.fr/offres/recherche/detail/136QBXM/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//* 
                            [@id="footer_tc_privacy_button_2"]'))).click()

ac = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
file_like_object = io.BytesIO(ac)
im = Image.open(file_like_object)
img_byte_arr = io.BytesIO()
file_like_object.save(img_byte_arr, format='PNG')
```

**What is the problem with my code? Are there any alternatives ?**

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that the connection couldn't be established.
I'll suggest to:

- validate the page is reachable
- validate proxi rules
- make sure firewall in not blocking
- clear browser cache

probably this may help you to shortcut the issue

Comment: Already checked everything you suggest and sadly nope still same issue.